# Static site generator using JavaScript Promises

Tags: javascript, file-system, ecmascript-6, asynchronous, promise

I have created a small static site generator (for learning purposes) in Javascript ES6, using Promises, but I am not certain of how to use them well. The code below works fine, but I wonder if i can't write my promises a better way.

I call my promises in `SSG.start();`

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs   = require('fs-extra');
const ejs  = require('ejs');
const md   = require('markdown-it')({
    html: true,
    linkify: true,
    typographer: true
});

let SSG = {
    outputFolder: '../output/',

    contentFolder: '../content/',

    assetsFolder: '../assets/',

    contentFiles: async function (dir, filelist) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
            filelist = filelist || [];
            files.forEach((file) => {
                if (fs.statSync(dir + '/' + file).isDirectory()) {
                    return resolve(contentFiles(dir + '/' + file, filelist));
                } else {
                    filelist.push(file);
                    return resolve(filelist);
                }
            });
        })
    },

    generateHTMLFile: async function (file) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            let fstream = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
            let params = fstream.match(/\+Params\+([\s\S]*?)\+\+\+/g);
            let content = fstream.match(/(\+Content[0-9]*\+|\+Content\+)([\s\S]*?)*(\+\+\+)/g);
            let contents = [];

            params = params[0].replace('+Params+', '').replace('+++', '');
            content = content[0].split('+++');

            try {
                params = yaml.safeLoad(params, 'utf8');
                for (it of content) {
                    it = it.replace('+++', '').replace(/(\+Content[0-9]*\+|\+Content\+)/g, '');
                    contents.push(md.render(it));
                }

                const funs = require('./functions.js');

                ejs.renderFile('../templates/' + params.template + '.ejs', {funs: funs, params: params, content: contents}, {}, (err, html) => {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    resolve({html: html, url: params.url});
                });

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    },

    saveHTML: function (html, url) {
        if (!fs.existsSync(this.outputFolder)) {
            fs.mkdir(this.outputFolder, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        }
        fs.writeFile(this.outputFolder + url + '.html', html, (err) => {
            if (err)  return console.log(err);
        });
    },

    saveStaticAssets: function () {
        fs.copySync(this.assetsFolder, this.outputFolder);
    },

    start: async function () {
        try {
            let time = Date.now();
            console.log('Génération des fichiers HTML...');

            let files = await this.contentFiles(this.contentFolder);

            for (file of files) {
                await this.generateHTMLFile(this.contentFolder + file).then(({html, url}) => {
                    this.saveHTML(html, url);
                });
            }

            this.saveStaticAssets();

            console.log('Généré en ' + (Date.now() - time) + 'ms');
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    }
};

(async () => {
    await SSG.start();
})();
```

What do you think about it ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Thanks for this good question - I hope you get some good reviews, and I hope to see more of your contributions here in future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that bother me is why `let SSG`? Why is it an object? If you're using ES6+ (as you do), I'd go with making this a class. It's more obvious and more readable. Note that while doing this, you'll have to alter the function signature, i.e. `generateHtmlFile: async function (file) { ... }` becomes `async generateHtmlFile(file) { ... }`.

Since you have folder names stored as a properties of your object (`outputFolder`, `contentFolder` and `assetsFolder`), they should be moved now to the constructor. There is also a good candidate for another new property on line 51: `../templates/` should be also extracted. This is because there are no properties in JS class ATM. Also, while we're on the topic of class properties, I'd suggest that you should pass an object with folder names as a constructor argument. That way you can easily change the folders you're using by just instantiating an object with another folder names. When we sum up the info about properties, here's what it should look like:

```
class SGG {
  constructor(folders = {}) {
    this.outputFolder = folders.outputFolder || '../output/'
    this.contentFolder = folders.contentFolder || '../content/'
    this.assetsFolder = folders.assetsFolder || '../assets/'
    this.templates = folders.templates || '../templates/'
  }
}
```

The second thing that I didn't notice when I looked at the code here is that you have a some implicit variables: `files` on line 19 and `it` on line 45. So just add `const` in front of those two and you'll be fine.

At line 49, there is a `require`. I'd move it to the top of the file because that way you know right on what are the dependencies of your file. And it's more cleaner code without some unexpected turns.

Now, to the methods. First one is `contentFiles` which is just a recursive call to find out all the files in a `contentFolder` directory. I see that you are probably confused with promises because you use `async` and `new Promise` in the same function. When making function an `async`, you should know that whatever you return from the function, it will be wrapped inside a promise and it also gives you the ability to use `await` inside it. But since you don't have `await` here, then there is no need for making this function an `async` one. You are already returning a promise. But, I think that you don't need a promise at all! You are using these `fs-extra` methods that are not returning a promise nor have a callback, so they are perfectly synchronous functions. Also, the `.forEach` got all of this tangled a bit, so if you remove it and use `for..of`, you can untangle yourself and get a cleaner code.

The next method, `generateHTMLFile` has similar issue with promises as the one above. From ejs' github, I noticed that if you don't pass the callback function, it will return a promise. So what should be done here is to remove `new Promise...` thing and keep `async` and rewrite the `ejs.renderFiles` not to use the callback function.

The method `saveHTML` is confusing a bit: you're using `sync` methods everywhere, but here you decided to go with `mkdir` instead of `mkdirSync` or `writeFileSync`.

Once you apply all of what I've said, you should get something like this:

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const md = require('markdown-it')({
    html: true,
    linkify: true,
    typographer: true,
});
const funs = require('./functions.js');

class SSG {
    constructor(folders = {}) {
        this.outputFolder = folders.output || '../output/'
        this.contentFolder = folders.contentFolder || '../content/'
        this.assetsFolder = folders.assetsFolder || '../assets/'
        this.templateFolder = folders.templateFolder || '../templates/'
    }

    contentFiles(dir, filelist) {
        const files = fs.readdirSync(dir)
        filelist = filelist || []
        for (const file of files) {
            if (fs.statSync(dir + '/' + file).isDirectory()) {
                contentFiles(dir + '/' + file, filelist)
            } else {
                filelist.push(file)
            }
        }
        return filelist
    }

    async generateHTMLFile(file) {
        const fstream = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
        let params = fstream.match(/\+Params\+([\s\S]*?)\+\+\+/g);
        let content = fstream.match(/(\+Content[0-9]*\+|\+Content\+)([\s\S]*?)*(\+\+\+)/g);
        let contents = [];

        params = params[0].replace('+Params+', '').replace('+++', '');
        content = content[0].split('+++');

        try {
            params = yaml.safeLoad(params, 'utf8');
            for (let it of content) {
                it = it.replace('+++', '').replace(/(\+Content[0-9]*\+|\+Content\+)/g, '');
                contents.push(md.render(it));
            }

             const html = await ejs.renderFile(this.templateFolder + params.template + '.ejs', {
                funs: funs,
                params: params,
                content: contents,
            }, {})

            return {
                html, 
                url: params.url,
            }

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    async saveHTML(html, url) {
        if (!fs.existsSync(this.outputFolder)) {
            await fs.mkdirSync(this.outputFolder, {recursive: true});
        }
        await fs.writeFileSync(this.outputFolder + url + '.html', html);
    }

    saveStaticAssets() {
        fs.copySync(this.assetsFolder, this.outputFolder);
    }

    async start() {
        try {
            let time = Date.now();
            console.log('Génération des fichiers HTML...');

            const files = this.contentFiles(this.contentFolder);

            for (const file of files) {
                await this.generateHTMLFile(this.contentFolder + file).then(({html, url}) => {
                    this.saveHTML(html, url);
                });
            }

            this.saveStaticAssets();

            console.log('Généré en ' + (Date.now() - time) + 'ms');
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    }
};

(async () => {
    const ssg = new SSG()
    await ssg.start();
})();
```

Last note that I'd like to make is that Node already has a pretty decent file system utilities. The only thing that I've noticed that is different from `fs-extra` is that `sync` functions do not return promises, but they rather act as a regular functions. Anyhow, I'd argue that you don't need `fs-extra` and use `fs` instead. But it's up to you.

I maybe missed something or maybe got into details and nitpicking more than needed, but this is a basic refactor that I would do to your code. I hope that I didn't break some things while doing this :)

---

**Edit:**
While looking at the code for the second time, I noticed that I've missed this line in `start`:

```
await this.generateHTMLFile(this.contentFolder + file).then(({html, url}) => {
    this.saveHTML(html, url);
});`
```

It's maybe just me, but I don't like this mixture of `await` and `then`.
I'd just suggest that if you're going with `await`, keep it that way.
My suggestion here would be to go with something like this:

```
const {html, url} = await this.generateHTMLFile(this.contentFolder + file)
await this.saveHTML(html, url)
```

I've also just noticed that you can optimize the solution for speed by awaiting on multiple promises:

```
await Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
    const {html, url} = await this.generateHTMLFile(this.contentFolder + file)
    await this.saveHTML(html, url)
}))
```

This way you start multiple promises *in parallel* (again, not a true parallelization since JS is single threaded) and await on all of them to finish before moving on. This way you'll get a bit faster execution. Note that if one promise throws and error, this line will also throw an error before waiting on the other promises to end.

Comment: Thanks for your review, i will adapt some things in my code. I have some questions and remarks. Why and how `contentFiles()` is not async or returning a Promise, because when I call it on `start()` I tell to await the method ? I have tested your method with and without async and both seems to work well, how can I be sure without a Promise or async that, in `start()`, `files` would get all files before iterate it in the `for .. of ..` below ?

Comment: Also I disagree with the removal of the Promise in `generateHTMLFile()`, I want my Promise return `html` & `url`, what I did in my code, but in yours I can't use the Promise of the EJS method for the next function I call : `saveHTML()`. I would let that part as is in my code.
FYI, I use `fs-extra` (which implements all `fs` methods) to use the `copySync()` method, I was a bit lazy about creating myself a function which does the same as `copySync()` =)

Thanks again for reviewing my code

Comment: @Thomas I missed to change `await contentFiles()` to `contentFiles()` in `start`. To answer your question from the first comment: you know this by looking inside `contentFiles` method. You are not calling any function that returns a promise there, so you can be sure that whatever `contentFiles` returns, it won't be a promise. Also, you're not stating that the function is `async`. All the methods you are using there are synchronous and the whole iteration will be done just as you imagine it: one by one. It won't run in parallel. [Contd. in next comment]

Comment: One more thing: promise doesn't mean parallel execution. Yes, you can have few promises running in _parallel_ (not truly parallel, but don't want to get into much JS details), but if you are looping over an array with `for..of` and have `await` inside it, it'll be done a sequential order.

Regarding the second comment and return value of `generateHTMLFile`, I'll update the code to address that also.

Answer (score 0):

### Review

Your code is a mess and breaks about every async rule in the book.

JavaScript is slow but because Node.js is event driven it can still deliver a very efficient server solution. However if you start using synchronous IO calls you negate any benefit that `node.js` provides and in effect turn a high throughput server into a slow dinosaur.

General advice is DON'T use synchronous calls if there is an asynchronous alternative.

### ???

What are you waiting to do? in...

```
(async () => {
    await SSG.start();
})();
```

You dont do anything after the function so in effect you have just made a complex version of

```
SSG.start();
```

### Use modern syntax

- When adding functions to an object use the function shorthand `saveStaticAssets: function () { ... },` becomes `saveStaticAssets() { ... },`
- Use object property shorthand if you have the variable names defined. eg `{funs: funs, params: params , content: content}` becomes `{funs, params, content}`
- Use parameter defaults  eg  `contentFiles: async function (dir, filelist) { /*...*/ filelist = filelist || [];` becomes `async contentFiles(dir, filelist = []) {`

### No need for Object `SSG`

You have created a module that contains a static single instance of SSG. There is no benefit gained by creating the object. All it does to force you to use a more verbose syntax when accessing references eg `this.foo` can be simply `foo`

### Try Catch?

Promises/Async come with error handling built in. You should not be using `try`, `catch` blocks in async and promise based code.

### Careful `console` may block

The [global console](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data) can be synchronous and thus is a blocking IO operation (blocks events) that flies in the face of the ideal of node.js being a non blocking event driven server.

Avoid logging to the `console` for all but the most important information tracking (even if not blocking console noise is bad)

### Rewrite

The rewrite assumes you only want the single static instance run once.

This rewrite is untested, somewhat of a guess as to your needs and is purely as example *only* It is not intended as a working alternative.

- Single error handler so stops on any error!!!
- All functions are `async`
- Removed the redundant `SSG` wrapper on functions and properties.
- Removed all synchronous `fs-extra` calls in favor of `async` versions.
- Using `await` to idle execution when ever possible.
- Uses `Promise.all` to handle `async` lists/arrays
- Moved folder names to Object `FOLDERS`
- Created `REGS` to hold `regExp` that where mixed with code. It is frozen to prevent mutation.
- Moved `const funs = require('./functions.js');` to local global scope.
- **Note** that this will exit before the final `fs.copy` is complete. If there is an error it will not be caught. Un-comment line below to `await` proper end.
- `start` and `contentFiles` may not work together at best possible performance (or at all) (I am assuming there is no dependency between files in `start` an the result of `contentFiles`)

.

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs   = require('fs-extra');
const ejs  = require('ejs');
const funs = require('./functions.js');
const md   = require('markdown-it')({html: true, linkify: true, typographer: true});
const FOLDERS = {output: '../output/', content: '../content/', assets: '../assets/'};
const REGS = Object.freeze({
    match: {
        constent: /(\+Content[0-9]*\+|\+Content\+)([\s\S]*?)*(\+\+\+)/g,
        param: /\+Params\+([\s\S]*?)\+\+\+/g
    },
    replace: {content: /(\+Content[0-9]*\+|\+Content\+)/g}
});
start().catch(e => console.error(e));

async function contentFiles(directory, filelist = []) {
    const files = await fs.readdir(directory);
    return (await Promise.all(files.map(async file => 
        (await fs.stat(directory+ '/' + file)).isDirectory() ? 
            contentFiles(directory+ '/' + file, filelist) : 
            file
    )));
}
async function generateHTMLFile(file) {
    const contents = [], fstream = await fs.readFile(file, 'utf8');
    const content = fstream.match(REGS.match.content)[0].split('+++');
    var params = fstream.match(REGS.match.params);
    params = yaml.safeLoad(
         params[0].replace('+Params+', '').replace('+++', ''), 'utf8'
    );
    for (item of content) {
        contents.push(md.render(
            item.replace('+++', '').replace(REGS.replace.content, '')
        ));
    }
    return ejs.renderFile(
        '../templates/' + params.template + '.ejs', {funs, params, content}, {}
    );
}
async function saveHTML({html, url}) {
    const createDir = await fs.exists(FOLDERS.output);
    if (createDir) { await fs.mkdir(FOLDERS.output, {recursive: true}) }
    await fs.writeFile(FOLDERS.output + url + '.html', html);
}
async function start() {
    await Promise.all(
        (await contentFiles(FOLDERS.content)).map(async file =>
            saveHTML(await generateHTMLFile(FOLDERS.content + file))
        )
    );
    fs.copy(FOLDERS.assets, FOLDERS.output);
    // return fs.copy(FOLDERS.assets, FOLDERS.output); // maybe return promise
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your review, I didn't knew the existence of `Object.freeze()` and some modern syntaxes, I have truly learned a lot.

Comment: Also I just wanted to point out including the function `writeFile();` on a ternary operator on `saveHTML();` is wrong, i want to write a file in either ways.

Comment: @Thomas Yes indeed that is what your code does, I will update the example.